# Tips for golfing in Cheddar

Tags: code-golf, tips

[image: Cheddar]

[Cheddar](https://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar) is a high-level, functional + object-oriented programming language created by our user [Downgoat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/40695/downgoat) designed to make programming easier, faster, and more intuitive.

What general tips do you have for golfing in Cheddar? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to Cheddar (e.g. "Remove unnecessary whitespace." is not an answer).

Answer (score 3):

## Use Functionized Properties

If you ever use just a property in a function:

```
A->A.long.property(n).foo.bar
```

You can use functionized properties to save some bytes:

```
@.long.property(n).foo.bar
```

You can reference the variable in the functionized property with `$0`.

Answer (score 2):

### Use the String Operator for string sequences

I'm talking about the **`@"`** operator which does different things, all of which deal with strings. This has quite a bit of uses but this is one of my favorite uses:

Take a look at this:

```
@" [103, 111, 97, 116, 115] === "goats"
```

not that useful but the opposite is:

```
@"'goats' === [103, 111, 97, 116, 115]
'goats'.bytes // compare the above too
```

This is especially useful to **generate the alphabet**:

```
65@"90    // Uppercase Alphabet
97@"122   // Lowercase Alphabet
65@"90+97@"122 // Both cases
String.letters // Compare 97@"122 to this
```

Answer (score 1):

### Curry

No not red curry (what other curry would you be thinking about ¬_¬). I mean this type of curry:

```
a->b->
```

If you have a function taking two arguments. It's shorter to curry than to not:

```
(a,b)->
a->b->
```

Note: This is only shorter when you have **exactly two** arguments.

Answer (score 1):

### Use default arguments

Declaring Cheddar variables can be quite the byte-waster:

```
->{var a=b+1}
```

luckily, you can (ab)use function default values for creating variables:

```
b=a+1->b
```

---

Here are some examples of uses:

```
let f= (a,b=a+1)->b
f(5) // 6

let f= a=Math.rand()->a
f() // 0.8757450950797647
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use Functionized Operators and Bonding

This is a simple one. If you have anything like:

```
i->1+i
```

or any similar operation. You can shorten using functionized operators + bonding:

```
1&(+)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use the mapping operator

The `=>` maps LHS to RHS, due to it's precedence, this also means you can use it with ranges and use it multiple times:

```
a=>f
(a).map(f)
```

Additionally:

```
a=>f=>g           // This is equivilant to...
(a).map(f).map(g) // this
```